# Ternary operator inside lambda expression doesn't work with null value

Tags: c#

I have the following query:

```
x.Organization.ClientActivityLogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.ActivityDate).Select(v =>
          v.Property.MailingAddress.Address1.ToLower() + ", " +
          v.Property.MailingAddress.Address2 == null ? "" 
                      :v.Property.MailingAddress.Address2.ToLower()
        ).FirstOrDefault()
```

Which works when used inside another query but gives me the following error when Adress2(string) is null while used on an object outside the query:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
    
    Jobba.DataLayer.Address.Address2.get returned null.
```

I don't quite understand why this is happening.

When I use `Address2.FirstOrDefault()` the error changed to:

> ```
> 'Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source'
> ```

Comment: It might be a simple order of operations here, it may be that the string concatenation is done before the ternary operation, and thus the resulting string is *not* null, try `+ (v....Address2 == null ? "" : ...)` as in add the extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the string concatenation is done before the ternary expression.

Essentially what you're doing is this:

```
(v.....Address1.ToLower() + ", " + v.....Address2) == null
    ? "" 
    :v.Property.MailingAddress.Address2.ToLower()
```

Since the expression is *not* null, it tries to grab the Address2 and then crashes.

The solution is to add parenthesis around the ternary expression:

```
... + (v.....Address2 == null ? "" : v.....Address2.ToLower())
```

This will isolate the ternary expression from the string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I don't know why I didn't think about that